# how to access kafka metrics data using dropwizard library

Tags: apache-kafka, metrics, jmx, dropwizard, yammer

Can somebody provide an example of how to access kafka metrics using dropwizard lib?

Below code uses yammer metrica to access the metric with the given metric Name

```
MetricName  metricName = new MetricName("", "", "", "", "kafka.server:type=ZooKeeperClientMetrics,name=ZooKeeperRequestLatencyMs");
Metric m = Metrics.defaultRegistry().allMetrics().get(metricName);


another example of accessing the metrics using yammer

for (Map.Entry<String, SortedMap<MetricName, Metric>> entry : getMetricsRegistry()
                .groupedMetrics(MetricPredicate.ALL)
                .entrySet()) {
                for (Map.Entry<MetricName, Metric> subEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                    final Metric metric = subEntry.getValue();
                    metric.processWith(this, subEntry.getKey(), epoch);                   
                }
            }



Does anybody know what is the equivalent code using dropwizard?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dropwizard-kafka` module, there already is a MetricsReporter built in

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-kafka/blob/4.0.x/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/kafka/metrics/DropwizardMetricsReporter.java